# Simple SQL Multi-Table Design

Tags: sql

Lets say I have a table of Classrooms.
[Classroom Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtSg6.jpg)

Each Classroom has its own set of Students specific to that Classroom. What would be the best way to set this up? Should I…

A. Make a separate Student table for each Classroom? How would I assign a Classroom to a table though?

B. Make one big list of Students each with their own Classroom FK? What if there are millions of Students and you are only looking for Students of a specific Classroom?

I am new to SQL btw

Comment: @NathanHughes It is a one to many relationship I believe. 1 classroom, many students

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest one table for each entity and a join table to describe the relationship between the two. So one table for all the students, another table for all the classrooms and another table for joining.

Minimal example

`STUDENT` table has columns `id` (integer, primary key) and `name` (varchar).

`CLASSROOM` table has columns `id` (integer, primary key) and `description` (varchar).

`STUDENT_CLASSROOM` has integer columns `id` (primary key), `student_id` and `classroom_id`.

This way students can be assigned to classrooms (or classrooms can be assigned to students) and you can declare your foreign keys as appropriate.